# Range(min, max, value) function in Java

Tags: java, methods

Sometimes we write unnecessary code. My question is pretty simple: is there a method like the following?

```
/** @return true if a given value is inside the range. */
public static boolean range(min, max, value)
```

I didn't find it on Google. Is that because it doesn't exist?

Comment: Do not name it `rangeCheck()`, Oracle will sue you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a typed `Range` class that has a `within` method:

```
public class Range<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    private final T min;
    private final T max;

    public Range( T min, T max ) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public boolean within( T value ) {
        return min.compareTo(value) <= 0 && max.compareTo(value) >= 0;
    }
}
```

If min and max were the same for a group of tests, you could reuse your `range` object for all tests.

FWIW, this seems kinda handy!

Comment: @OpDeCirkel Thanks for picking that up. I just typed it in without an IDE and without thinking! Fixed now - Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Apache Commons Lang has a number of Range implementations, including [NumberRange](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberRange.html).

Commons Lang 3 has a [generic implementation](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/Range.html).

Answer (score 2):

um...

```
value >= min && value <= max
```

surely if you really need a function for that you can easily write it yourself?

Comment: On the other hand, `Math.abs()` exists, and it's an even simpler impl

Comment: value >= min && value <= max is what i always use... It`s because i`m going to use it like: 35 times... and would be annoying to do it for every clause... Thanks!

Comment: @Ivan Seidel: it has 29 characters. The function call would have 23. I bet you there are far, far bigger annoyances you could spend your time on.

Comment: -1, I believe OP was requesting a library alternative to favor a more recognizable pattern and avoid writing a custom implementation. This answer is obvious and unhelpful.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't exist.

A 'sensible' place for it would be in the Math module, but since it's quite simply expressed in the expression

```
min < value && value < max
```

it seems a little excessive.

Comment: I know it`s simple, as Math.abs() is simple, but better than (val <0? val*-1: val)

Comment: Well, `abs` is a Java method with a mathematical equivalent. Also, it returns an integer. `range` is a boolean test that returns true or false and has no real mathematical equivalent. Indeed, in a real world situation, the test that a value is within some numerical range would probably have a more useful name from the problem domain, such as `isAValidChoice(min, max, value)`... indeed the `min` and `max` would probably be fields belonging to whichever class provided the `isAValidChoice` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean withinRange(min, max, value){
    return (value >= min && value <= max);
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your answer and why it successfully answers the question? - from review